# Row Back Calculation or update row value by new previous value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `dataframe` and need update my column values conditionally but it is the most important that it must be updated for each iter.

Latest, i changed my logic but again it didn't work. I need help in Python!!!!

I have tried lots of function such as `shift(), lag` ... but they doesn't hold updated value of previous row. I don't want to try while or other loop techniques because of performance. Please help quickly and high performance computing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'GROUP':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A'], 'DURUM':['DEL', 'DEL', 'DEL', 'DEL', 'DEL'], 'SV':[0,0,0,0,0], 'V':[0,0,0,0,0]} 

data=pd.DataFrame(data)

def update_frame(data):
    last_expected = None
    def apply_logic(row):
        nonlocal last_expected
        last_row_id =  row.name - 1
        if row.name == 0:
            last_expected = row['DURUM']
            return last_expected
        last_row = data.iloc[[last_row_id]].iloc[0].to_dict()
        last_expected = 'PHA' if last_row['GROUP'] == row['GROUP'] and last_row['DURUM']=='DEL' and row['SV']>= 0.0 and row['V']==0.0  else row['DURUM']
        return last_expected
    return apply_logic
data['DURUM']= data.apply(update_frame(data), axis=1)
```

Expected is respectively `DURUM=DEL,PHA,DEL,PHA,DEL`

Actual is respectively `DURUM=DEL PHA,PHA,PHA,PHA,PHA`